# Getting error on returning collection view cell

Tags: ios, xcode

1.I am using two collection views for two different designs and . subclasss the two different cells but i am getting error at below method 
it showing missing return function but i have give return the cells
2. shall i use singel collectinon view sub class for both different layoutas has given through   storyboard

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
if collectionView ==  similarProductCollection || collectionView == moreShpsColectionView
{      
 var productCell = SimilarProductCollectionViewCell()
if collectionView ==  similarProductCollection
{
    productCell=similarProductCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collecCell", for: indexPath) as! SimilarProductCollectionViewCell
    return productCell
}
else{
   // productCell=NSNull
    var shopsCell = MoreShpsCollectionViewCell()
shopsCell=moreShpsColectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"moreCell", for: indexPath) as! MoreShpsCollectionViewCell

  return shopsCell
}  
}

}
```

Comment: You haven't specified any else case for the top if condition
if collectionView ==  similarProductCollection || collectionView == moreShpsColectionView

Answer (score 1):

this if false:

```
if collectionView ==  similarProductCollection || collectionView == moreShpsColectionView
{ 
}
```

returns nothing

**Example:**

```
func someFunction() -> Bool {

  let something = true

    if(something){

      return true

    }

}
```

This will produce an Error even if you are 100% sure it will work. You would need to change it to:

```
func someFunction() -> Bool {

  let something = true

    if(something){

      return true

    }else{

      return false

    }

}
```

Comment: its returning and its true

Comment: Yeah but xcode can't know that if you compile. You need to add at least a default return if it's false. Even if this case will never happen.

Comment: @macwinfdo i added an example

Answer (score 0):

Use like below :

showing missing return function mean you are not return any cell in outer block so write condition like below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
if collectionView ==  similarProductCollection 
{      
 var productCell = SimilarProductCollectionViewCell()

    productCell=similarProductCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collecCell", for: indexPath) as! SimilarProductCollectionViewCell
    return productCell

}else{
// productCell=NSNull
    var shopsCell = MoreShpsCollectionViewCell()
shopsCell=moreShpsColectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"moreCell", for: indexPath) as! MoreShpsCollectionViewCell

  return shopsCell
}

}
```

Comment: downvoter what is wrong with that code,

What does mean showing missing return function?

Comment: I guess you got downvoted because your function has the same problem as OP was asking for. Your code gives an error because it returns nothing if the outer if fails.

Comment: i am returing cell else block also check clear, any how he has to return cell in else block also

Answer (score 0):

Use like below, its may be work.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
var cell: UICollectionViewCell?
if collectionView ==  similarProductCollection 
{      
cell = similarProductCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collecCell", for: indexPath) as! SimilarProductCollectionViewCell
}else{
cell = moreShpsColectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"moreCell", for: indexPath) as! MoreShpsCollectionViewCell
}
return cell
}
```

Comment: if there is other than those collection views then it returns a cell of pointed by nil...ie..no cell retuns.